# Allow access to subset of K8 resources

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I granted read access to pod

Sample:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount sa1 

kubectl create role pod-reader --verb=get --resource=pods

kubectl create rolebinding sa1-binding --serviceaccount=default:sa1 --role=pod-reader
```

Is there any way to restrict this access to selected pods on the basis of metadata or labels?

Comment: There was a request to be able to manage RBAC over labels, but that feature isn't implemented:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44703



You can use resourceNames for explicitly listing pods you want to provide access to as mentioned here : 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/56582


Details:

Comment: @dev1918 I like the `resourceNames` approach. You can add it as an answer if you like.

Comment: glad, it helps. Have added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can use `resourceNames` to provide access to selected resources.

Here is an excerpt from k8s [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources).

Example,

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: configmap-updater
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing ConfigMap
  # objects is "configmaps"
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  resourceNames: ["my-configmap"]
  verbs: ["update", "get"]
```

> Also, You cannot restrict create or deletecollection requests by resourceName. For create, this limitation is because the object name is not known at authorization time.

Comment: edited the answer to add example and improve formatting,

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to limit roles to certain labels. Actually there was an issue related to this opened here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44703

With RBAC you're specifying access to resources, which are part of API groups and you select what verbs can be executed - that's all.